# Resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I have this class

```
public class DaoMaster extends AbstractDaoMaster {
    public static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1605131322;

    /** Creates underlying database table using DAOs. */
    public static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
        ApplicationConfigDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
        RequestCacheDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
    }

    /** Drops underlying database table using DAOs. */
    public static void dropAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifExists) {
        ApplicationConfigDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
        RequestCacheDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
    }

    public static abstract class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public OpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Creating tables for schema version " + SCHEMA_VERSION);
            createAllTables(db, false);
        }
    }

    /** WARNING: Drops all table on Upgrade! Use only during development. */
    public static class DevOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {

        public DevOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
            dropAllTables(db, true);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DaoMaster(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super(db, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        registerDaoClass(ApplicationConfigDao.class);
        registerDaoClass(RequestCacheDao.class);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession() {
        return new DaoSession(db, IdentityScopeType.Session, daoConfigMap);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession(IdentityScopeType type) {
        return new DaoSession(db, type, daoConfigMap);
    }    
}
```

And then another class

**UPDATE** 
as pointed by some of you, it seems my naming convention is bad, what a stupid basic mistake, so i update them to the following

```
public class DbHelper {
    public static final String LOGIN_DATA_PREFIX = "LOGIN_DATA_";
    public DaoMaster DAOMaster;
    public DaoSession DAOSession;
    public DaoMaster.OpenHelper openHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDb;

    private Context context;

    public static class CONSTANT {
        public static String DB_FILE_NAME = "app.db";

        /* Define all DAO Property Constant Here */

        public static class APPLICATION_CONFIG {
            public static String DAO_NAME = "applicationconfig";
            public static String PROPERTY_ID = "Id";
            public static String PROPERTY_KEY = "Key";
            public static String PROPERTY_VALUE = "Value";
        }

        public static class REQUEST_CACHE{
            public static String DAO_NAME = "requestcache";
            public static String PROPERTY_URL = "Url";
            public static String PROPERTY_METHOD = "Method";
            public static String PROPERTY_PARAM = "Param";
            public static String PROPERTY_ID = "Id";
        }

        //...

    }

    public class DAOWrapper {
        private DaoSession session;

        /* Load all DAO Here */
        public ApplicationConfigDao ApplicationConfig;
        public RequestCacheDao RequestCache;
        // ...

        public DAOWrapper(DaoSession session){
            this.session = session;

            /* Init all DAO Here */
            this.ApplicationConfig = this.session.getApplicationConfigDao();
            this.RequestCache = this.session.getRequestCacheDao();
            // ...
        }
    }

    public DAOWrapper DAO;

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.openHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this.context, CONSTANT.DB_FILE_NAME, null);
        this.SQLiteDb = this.openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.DAOMaster = new DaoMaster(this.SQLiteDb);
        this.DAOSession = this.DAOMaster.newSession();
        this.DAO = new DAOWrapper(this.DAOSession);
    }

    ...
}
```

**But it is still fail**

and then init the class

```
this.Db = new DbHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

but it throw error during create instance DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper, and it is said that it can't found the class DevOpenHelper, whats wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**
**Error Console**

```
5-15 23:22:31.313  20424-20424/com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin.dao.DaoMaster$DevOpenHelper', referenced from method com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin.DbHelper.<init>
05-15 23:22:44.190  20424-20424/com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin, PID: 20424
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin.dao.DaoMaster$DevOpenHelper
            at com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin.DbHelper.<init>(DbHelper.java:86)
            at com.itp.android.suitetreatadmin.App.onCreate(App.java:108)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i know there are some similar questions, but i think this is case by case problem,

Thank you for for your help.

Comment: first of all try to use clean and assemble from Gradle if you use AndroidStudio

Comment: Your naming conventions are not good.. You can not give a variable name same as class name.!!

Comment: updated, i modify them but it still throw same error

Comment: I try you code, and it work correct. May be problem somewhere else?

Comment: i will try to clean  + rebuild + uninstall old app

Comment: Di you figure out the solution ?

Comment: no, i think the cause is when there are too many method inside project it will cause this problem, i remove some dependencies and it resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

in class DbHelper you cant give the object name same as class name so you must change the name of object like

```
DaoMaster daoMaster;
DaoSession daoSession;
```

Comment: updated, i modify them but it still throw same error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue my DBHelper calss was not loading throwing an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

In comments 1214 mentioned this might be issue `too many methods` that is memory related problem. So I tested on one device with small memory API version 19, it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, but same app works on other device with API 21 and better memory hardware than previos device.

Hence this must be memory issue or android version issue.